# .net 6 use http on localhost api

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm trying to run my webapi under http on localhost so in the program.cs, I have

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
else
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

but when I run the api, it still redirects to https and if I try to use http it says localhost cannot load any data.  I'm also definitely in development as the swagger ui is displayed.

Is there something else I need to do to run the api under http?

Appsettings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnection": "From user secrets"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: how your kestrel configuration looks like in the appSettings?

Comment: I don't think I'm using kestrel, have edited question to show appsettings

Comment: do clean and build and check then. sometimes it does not rebuild this  automaticly, also look for      "applicationUrl": in launchSettings.json and make shure that http and https is present there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was my launchSettings.json:

```
"API": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": false,
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:7188",  <-- this line was set to https, changing it to http fixed the issue
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the listening end points in manually.

```cs
.UseKestrel(options =>
 {
   // HTTP 8088
   options.ListenLocalhost(8088);
 }
```

also, `.UseUrls("http://*:8088")` may work